# vendor/autoload.php: failed to open stream

Tags: php, instagram-api

I worked with a project using composer.But when i run the index file,system shows the following error,

```
Warning: require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\instagram_php\index.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\instagram_php\index.php on line 5
```

I have installed composer from https://getcomposer.org/.
What am doing wrong?

Comment: If you have installed correctly, then just go to your working directory and run "cmposer update" command.

Comment: I installed composer in D: so it shows the following error

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>composer update
Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visua
l Studio 9.0\VC
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the
https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: there must be a composer.json file it fetches all your external repositories and manage everything.

Comment: If you do not yet have a composer.json file, start by using `composer require <the package you needed>`. I assume that you installed composer because you needed it to install some package, isn't it?

Comment: Already I have **composer.json** file.

Comment: Where i want to have this composer.json file.

Comment: It should be in the project root directory

Comment: Is this `composer.json` file want to contain any functions.

Comment: When i run `composer update` command in cmd prompt it shows the following,                                                                                                             You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Comment: How to enable SSL/TLS protection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `require_once`with a relative path. It is possible but there are so many things that can go wrong that I usually avoid it.

Where is the `vendor`folder relative to `index.php`? I recommend using an absolute path. You can use the magic constants to determine it:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```

NOTE: you can use `/..` to go up the directory tree.

NOTE2: `__DIR__` requires php 5.3 or higher. You can use `dirname(__FILE__)` for older versions.

Comment: I don't have a folder like **vendor**

Comment: composer will create the vendor folder when you run it (you should run it from the project root folder). See my comment to the question above

Comment: Thank you..Composer creates the `vendor` folder.

Comment: How to run composer in my project root? I am facing the same issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure **vendor** folder is there if not please Run following command:-

> composer install